# Chef::Exceptions::UnresolvableGitReference error when Deploying an OpsWorks app

Tags: git, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I only posting this to help others, since I already have the answer; no up votes needed.

I encountered this error message in my OpsWorks logs after a deployment error:

`Chef::Exceptions::UnresolvableGitReference: Unable to parse SHA reference for '*branch name*' in repository '*repository name*'`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution. Like a bonehead, I had forgotten to push the branch in question to the remote (origin) repository.

In other news, today is my 308th birthday (okay, maybe I'm not *that* Samuel Johnson).